# How to process CSS file with custom loader in viteJS?

Tags: webpack, bundler, vite

how can I tell ViteJS to load *.css files from specific path to load with custom loader like sass?
example in webpack:

```
{
                test: /ckeditor5-[^/\\]+[/\\]theme[/\\].+\.css$/,
                use: [ 'sass-loader' ]
},
```

Comment: Sass is supported out of the box, but you need [to install `sass` in your project](https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#css-pre-processors) to enable it. Is that enough to cover your use case?